# Why is my parameter only processing one value

Tags: powershell

I played around with parameters and I ran into a problem.

```
function sign-script {
param(
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline = $true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
        Position = 0,
        Mandatory = $true        
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [Alias('FullName')]
    [string[]]$scripts,
    [string]$certname = "codesigning",
    [string]$certstore = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
)

Write-Host $scripts.count

}
```

If I run this function like this:

```
"Z:\test\test-sign.ps1","Z:\test\test-sign - Kopie (7).ps1" | sign-script
```

`$scripts.count` returns 1, instead of 2, why? Is the function not processing all values, or is it only accepting one value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need a `Process {}` block to act on each item.

By default, with no `Begin`, `End`, or `Process` block, you only have an `End`, so you're only operating with the last item passed in.

```
function sign-script {
param(
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline = $true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
        Position = 0,
        Mandatory = $true        
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [Alias('FullName')]
    [string[]]$scripts,
    [string]$certname = "codesigning",
    [string]$certstore = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
)

Process {
    Write-Host $scripts.count
}

}
```

If you do it this way, you're going to see `1` returned twice. This is expected, because the process block gets called once per item.

Whereas if you call it like this:

```
sign-script "Z:\test\test-sign.ps1","Z:\test\test-sign - Kopie (7).ps1"
```

Then it will return `2`.

The way I typically handle this is to use `foreach` in the process block:

```
Process {
    foreach ($script in $scripts) {
        Write-Host $script
    }
}
```

This ensures that you're always dealing with a single script in the innermost loop whether scripts were specified via pipeline or parameter.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you didn't split function body into blocks: `begin`, `process` and `end`.

- `begin` block is executed before first item is arrived from pipeline
- `process` block is executed for each item in pipeline
- `end` block is executed after last item is recieved from pipeline.

If no blocks are defined, function body is implicitly set to `end` bblock. As the result, you will see only last item in pipeline. To fix that, I would suggest to rewrite the script as follows:

```
function sign-script {
param(
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline = $true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
        Position = 0,
        Mandatory = $true        
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [Alias('FullName')]
    [string[]]$scripts,
    [string]$certname = "codesigning",
    [string]$certstore = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
)
    process {
        Write-Host $scripts.count
    }
}
```

you just put the code that is supposed to process each item in pipeline into `process` block. When you run the script, you will see `1` twice, because `process` block is restarted for each item.